# Show that if a Mobius transformation has 3 fixed points then it is the identity map.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have that any non trivial Mobius transformation has at most 2 fixed points since f(z)-z=0 has at most 2 roots. But I cannot deduce why it must then be the identity.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $Tz=(az+b)/(cz+d)$.  The fixed points of $T$ must satisfy the equation:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=z & \iff az+b=cz^2+dz\\
& \iff cz^2+(d-a)z+b=0
\end{align}$$

If this quadratic equation has more than 3 solutions, the polynomial must be identically zero. So, $c=0,a=d,b=0$.

Therefore $Tz=az/a=z$.

This argument works when either $a\ne0$ or $d\ne0$.  If either one is zero, then $a=b=c=d=0$ which is impossible.

Comment: What about if z is infinity? Does this proof still apply?

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma:** If $f$ fixes $1,0,\infty$, it must be the identity map.

**Proof:** Indeed, take:
$$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

Because it fixes $0$, then $b=0$. Because it fixes $\infty$ then, $f(z)=\frac{a}{c+d/z}$ must have $c=0$ and we have $f(z)=az/d$. But it fixes $1$, so $f(z)=z$. $\square$

**Theorem:** If $f$ fixes any distinct three points, it must be the identity map.

**Proof:** I will assume you know Mobius transformation are invertible. You can prove this by explicitly writing the inverse, or by realizing every Mobius transformation is associated to an invertible linear transformation.

Suppose $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ fix three points $a,b,c$. Clearly $f^{-1}$ and $\tilde{f}^{-1}$ also fix these points. Consider the map:

$$g(z)=\frac{(a-c)(z-b)}{(a-b)(z-c)}$$

$g$ takes $a$ to $1$, $b$ to $0$ and $c$ to $\infty$. The determinant is $(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)\not=0$ by hypothesis, so it is a Mobius transformation. Define:

$$h=g\circ \tilde{f}\circ f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$$

This fixes $1,0,\infty$, so by our lemma it is the identity, which in turn implies $\tilde{f}\circ f^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ g=I$ and $\tilde{f}=f$. $\square$